# xls file is corrupted after upgrading apache poi from version 4.0.1 to the latest versions ( version 4.1.2 and version 5.0.0)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, excel-2016, hssfworkbook

The below code  works fine with apache poi version 4.0.1 but after upgrading apache poi to the latest versions (version 4.1.2 or version 5.0.0) the xls file generated is corrupted and when i try to open it i cannot find any data inside. (the size of the xls file after upgrading the poi.jar was updated from 4KO to 0KO.)

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public abstract class ExcelExporter
{ 
    public static void exportPanel(String account, JTable table) {
        FileOutputStream excel = null;
        try {   
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sh = wb.createSheet("hello");
            Row row = sh.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(1);
            excel = new FileOutputStream("WORKBOOK.xls");
            wb.write(excel);
            wb.close();
            excel.flush();
            excel.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Could you please advise?
Thanks,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R29pp.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbFec.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! I don't know much about apache poi, but I think you should provide more details to help the community help you, such as your execution log, how you use the given class, etc

Comment: Hi Jissay, thanks for you feedback. I am using the the API org.apache.poi to create an excel document with java code . I am using the class HSSFWorkbook as described in the code above to create an xls file. The same code works fine before the upgrade of the apache poi.jar to the latest version.

Comment: I wonder why such a simple case would slip us through and you are the first after that time since the release. So multiple invocations from your swing app or a file lock on Workbook.xls from another code part come to my mind.

Comment: Hi kiwiwings, thanks for your feedback. When I downgrade the poi.jar to 4.0.1 the same code generate a correct xls file but when I only upgrade the poi.jar to the latest version 5.0.0 the same code generate 0 KB xls file.

Comment: I want to add that I need to use the latest version of org.apache.poi to avoid the black duck vulnerability scan result.

Comment: Not reproducible. This simple code works for me using `apache poi 4.1.2` and `5.0.0` and produces a usable `WORKBOOK.xls`. Of course not clear how `String account` and `JTable table` are involved here and how exactly you are calling `public static void exportPanel(String account, JTable table)`. So, as @kiwiwings told already, the problem must be outside this simple code.

Comment: Hi Axel,thanks for your reply. I reduced the code to test a simple code of creating excel with hssfworbook in the old and the new version of poi.jar this is why I am not using here the account and the table parameters to fill the workbook cells.

Comment: Hi Axel,The issue is till reproducible on my side even after the creation of the workbook.xls in  the main method:
public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  try { 
   
   Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
   Sheet sh = wb.createSheet("hello");
   Row row = sh.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(1);
   FileOutputStream excel = new FileOutputStream("WORKBOOK.xls");
   wb.write(excel);
   wb.close();
   excel.flush();
   excel.close();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   
  }
 } , do I need additional jars to make it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding commons-math3.jar to my project.

Comment: OMG I've lost 3 hours to resolve the same problem, thx!